# Как подключиться к нескольким БД MSSQL в Laravel 5.4

Tags: sql-server, laravel

есть 1 база на локальном сервере (с ней все хорошо, миграции работают все просто отлично) и нужно подключиться еще к 1 базе на удаленном сервере (для переноса нескольких таблиц в мою базу на локальном сервере). Вопрос как мне настроить подключение ко 2 базе и забрать с нее все данные из нескольких таблиц?

Подскажите пожалуйста в config/database.php я добавил второе подключение как

```
'sqlsrv' => [
'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '###.#.#.#'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '#####'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '#######'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '###########'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '###########'),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'prefix' => '',
],
'sqlsrv_second' => [
'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
'host' => env('DB_HOST', '###.#.#.#'),
'port' => env('DB_PORT', '####'),
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', '########'),
'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '#################'),
'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '#######################'),
'charset' => 'utf8',
'prefix' => '',
],
```

На этом собственно все и остановилось. надо ли что - то указывать в файле .env и вообще последовательность действий какая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этого достаточно, чтобы получить данные с удаленного подключения используйте следующий подход:

```
$users = DB::connection('sqlsrv_second')->select(...);
```

Если же вы хотите через Eloquent получать данные с другого подключения указывайте в моделе аттрибут `connection`:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv_second';
}
```

Comment: Да я добрался до этого. Через php artisan tinker проверяю подключения и упираюсь уже в то, что подключение настроено верно, но у меня php 5.6.4 и я работаю с sql версии 11 а вторая база на 10 версии, которую как я понимаю php 5.6.4 не поддерживает. Как поступить в такой ситуации.?

Comment: @user9219705 меня версию PHP раз не поддерживает, вариантов больше нет же.

Comment: Если основной проект работает на laravel 5.4 и php 5.6.4 как я смогу поменять версию??? и я никогда не поверю что к примеру занимаясь разработкой на чем-то более новом для подключения к старой версии mssql нет никаких способов реализации

Comment: @user9219705 как по мне нет ничего сложного в миграции на новую версию PHP, с версией фреймворка может быть чуть тяжелее но тоже реализуемо, а поводу способов реализации это уже другой вопрос.